# How play(), pause(), stop() functions work while using rive with Android Development in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rive, kotlin-android

I am trying to add a progress bar from rive to my android with kotlin, but when every i use play(), pause(), stop() methods, app crash.

Can anyone plz, explain how to solve this and i have seen there are so many arguments we have to pass while using play() method. So can anyone please tell that one also.

Explain how to work with play(), pause(), stop() methods and which parameters we need to provide to work this methods in Android Development in kotlin with rive animation.

Comment: If you want help on a crash, post your code and the full stack trace.

Comment: Since it is confidential so, i cannot

Comment: Just i need the parameters use and types of play() stop() pause() method from this url https://help.rive.app/runtimes/playback